# Board to board connectivity

Tags: connector, board, ribbon-cable, cable-assemblies

Need to connect two boards together. Initially I thought about using a ribbon cable like [this one](https://ro.farnell.com/amp-te-connectivity/1483350-2/micromatch-4way-150mm/dp/1056208), but everything I found was significantly longer than what I needed (~30mm max). Are there any other options to achieve a similar result, that I'm maybe completely missing?

LE: I need to connect four signals, one I2C bus, ground and vcc. Current consumption is around 10mA.

Comment: google `mezanine connector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just cut the ribbon down to length and buy some connectors.

Comment: And it's really quite easy to both cut the cable and install the connectors. You don't need any special tools if you're just making a small number of them.

Answer (score 5):

You can buy a roll of ribbon cable and a bag of connectors and make the cable to the exact length you need.

Comment: I missed the fact that you can build the ribbon cable using IDC connectors. That looks like the way to go, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Sometimes (especially if the cable is similar to one with a popular purpose, such as raspberry pi gpio, or in the old days floppy drives) it's actually cheaper to buy a ribbon cable assembly and a loose connector, than to buy all the discrete parts.  (Or in ones teenage hobby years, carefully remove and re-use the connector).   A vise is a good tool for installing them.